# Build a GUI Application for Windows in C

Tags: c, winapi, user-interface

I'm fairly new to C programming.

My program is running at the console as expected, but now I want to build a really simple Windows GUI application for it, sticking to C (just a window showing some text and a file menu).

So far, I have built everything in a single .c source code and used MinGW gcc in my Windows PC as the compiler.

I just downloaded Visual Studio 2013, but trying to use it was a bit overwhelming. I tried to look for alternatives but I'm confused with all the terminology (IDE, SDK, API etc.) and what I really need to do what I want to.

I'll be really satisfied if you just point something for me to read in order to clear my mind.

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry if this was a bad question.

Comment: What about using the VS application wizzard (assuming its still around in 2013). It starts up (for 2010) if you create a new project.

Comment: For very simple C GUIs, I have often used Pelles C, which comes with a resource editor where you can design your dialog. You have to do a lot of the plumbing by hand though - but that's all part of the fun.

Comment: Read Petzold Programming Windows and you will be good to go.

Comment: IDE: Integrated Development Environment - a piece of software that bundles compiler, editor, project manager, form builders, debugger tools... all in one. SDK: Software Development Kit - A bundle of libs, built around a specific API, optionally (and often) including specific tools to facilitate the dev process. API: Application Programming Interface: piece of software (libs) by which your program can interface with another service/application. ie: connecting to a db through `mysql_real_connect`, using the MySQL C API (`#include <mysql.h>`)

Comment: If you want a GUI, persevere with the IDE.  The boilerplate wndprocs, message-handling and event-handlers are best provided by something that already works, (mostly:).

Answer (score 4):

A very simple GUI application is possible sticking with C and Windows API only.

In short, you have to register your own Window class (`RegisterClassEx`), then create the window (`CreateWindowEx`). Note that your window class main element is its (`WindowProc`) that receive the messages and that you have to implement to act as you want. After that, your C program should run the message pump (`PeekMessage` and `DispatchMessage`) for Windows to do its stuff and allow interacting with your window.

See the MSDN documentation for these functions to get help and examples.

Answer (score 2):

YOu can start learning GTK for developing GUI using C language . you can get the same at 
http://www.gtk.org/development.php

Comment: I'd say GTK is a horrible option for developing GUI applications on Windows.

Comment: Could you please tell me why do you think so ?

Comment: Have you ever *used* a GTK application on Windows? The experience is dreadful and the GTK project seemingly doesn't even want to provide a better one. Sure, it works somewhat, but it's far from something I would voluntarily subject users to. When developing for a single platform anyway I'd rather stick to native widgets or wrappers that at least try emulating them properly. GTK is fine if you target Gnome or Linux in general, but on Windows I feel it's very out of place.